# AWS SDK for .net. How to set PutObjectRequest filename

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MS3IS3PutObjectPutObjectRequestNET35.html

I want to use a MemoryStream to supply the request.InputStream. How can I set the filename S3 is to use when creating the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you need is `Key`, which is the relative path from the root of your bucket, excluding the initial `/`.

For example:

`folder/subfolder/file.txt`

See [PutObject sample 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TS3PutObjectRequestNET35.html) here.

Comment: ah, ok. Their example did not use a filename for key, so that threw me. Thanks.